# Why flicker API tags don't get input value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api

Why, when I input in `var title = $("myInput").value()`, API tags don't get value? If I insert directly value - `var title = "some text"`, it works!

```js
(function() {
    var flickerAPI = "https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?&api-key=d1c0be70688307ed71f305474f32c559&secret=04bb4c80a0753d23";
    $("#submit").click(function() {
        var title = $("myInput").value();
        $.getJSON(flickerAPI, {
          tags: title,
          tagmode: "all",
          format: "json"
        }).done(function(data) {
          $.each(data.items, function(i, item) {
            $("<img>").attr("src", item.media.m).appendTo("#images");
            if (i === 3) {
              return false;
            }
          });
        });
      }
    });
  });
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>FlowersApp</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="flowerStyle.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="getvalJavaScript.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="center" id="images"> </div>
  <div id="inputDiv">
    <input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Title..." value="">
    <button id="submit"> submit</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your selector is missing a `#` and also you have a syntax problem with the parentheses. If you run the snippet you'll see the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Simple typo... you are lacking the hash here which identifies the target as an ID:

```
var title = $("#myInput").value();
```

Comment: Did this answer help? :)